Roslyn script not executing properly from library/nuget
I am trying to use C# Roslyn scripting in a project. I have written some class which has code reading a file which contains the script, execute it and return the result. If this class is present in the same project, its working fine. But if its coming from a Nuget library(which I am testing using local nuget source so its easy to change library code and test quickly), which is a common library created for different execution classes for my use-case, its not working and returning the contents of the script.
        var scriptPath = payload.Get(Constants.Source) as string;
        var script = _fileReader.ReadFile(scriptPath);
        
        var options = ScriptOptions.Default
            .AddReferences(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AddReferences(typeof(object).Assembly)
            .AddReferences(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                               .Where(assembly => !assembly.IsDynamic && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(assembly.Location)))
            .AddImports("System", "System.Collections.Generic")
            .WithOptimizationLevel(OptimizationLevel.Release)
            .WithAllowUnsafe(false)
            .WithCheckOverflow(true);
            
        var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(script, options, globals: new CodeExecutorInput { Data = new Dictionary<string, object>() })
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var output = new JObject {
            [Constants.DEFAULT_OUTPUT_KEY] = JToken.FromObject(result)
        };
        success(new DefaultOutput<JObject>(output)); //This is an Action delegate` 

I have tried adding all the references as mentioned in the code snippet but nothing seems to be working.
If class present in same project -> {"result": 16}
If class present in Nuget -> {"result": "int test = 0;\nvar count = test + 15;\ncount++;\nreturn count;"}
Expectation for class in Nuget is same as class in same project i.e. {"result": 16}

What do you expect the result objects are going to be?

Expectation for class in Nuget is same as class in same project i.e. {"result": 16}, updated in the question as well.
